# Cosmos DB: MongoDB sort query returning blank resultset

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am using [Mongoose.js 4.11.6](http://mongoosejs.com/)  Node.js 6.0.

I have a user document which looks like bellow -

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: '' },
  email: { type: String, default: '' },
  phone: { type: String, default: '' },
  hashed_password: { type: String, default: '' },
  role: { type: String, default: '' },
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I am running following mongoose query -

> UserSchema.find({ role: options.role })
>         .select(options.select)
>         .sort({ 'email': -1 })
>         .exec(cb);

Ideally this should return the list matching user sorted by email id. The query works exactly what it is expected to do in our AWS deployment. 
But in the Cosmos DB MongoDB hosting it is returning the empty resultset. But the query return results (but not in desired order) when the .sort({ 'email': -1 }) is removed.

Comment: Have you tried just passing `'-email'` as sort parameter?

Comment: Have you opted into proper range indexing for the email? You can't do sorts on strings without setting the precision appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed in a separate thread this does indeed work. Below is the complete sample code showing sorting working as expected with CosmosDB & the Mongo API via Mongoose.

https://gist.github.com/m-gagne/00893a32a0e4c7f593a1676ba1380e63

```node
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('<COSMOS DB CONNECTION STRING>');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, default: '' },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, "users");

User.find({}).select(['email']).sort({ 'email': -1 }).exec(function(err, results) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("!!! ERROR !!!");
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using **Cosmos Db document**, has same issue with string field.
Problem is when I create collection, policyIndex default was

```
{
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
```

Hash Type is not good for order, change it to Range and working well

```
{
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
```